# React bootstrap carousel displayed in a grid

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

So im fetching data(images) from the server, and rendering them using bootstrap carousels on the page. However when I render the images, the carousels stack on top of each other and do not spread out horizontally across the page, but vertically. Im wondering why? maybe something with my bootstrap layout of coloumns or something? or do i pass styles to the object so it displays like and inline block? Is there a way to make them spread out horizontal like a grid?

```
const ImageCarousel = React.createClass({

getInitialState(){
 return null
},

componentWillMount() {
  this.props.fetchDiscovery()
},

renderImages(images) {
  var output = images.map((image) => {
    return(
        <CarouselItem >
          <img wdith={900} height={500} style={style.carousel} src={image.url} />
          <h3>Heya world</h3>
          <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
        </CarouselItem>

      )
    });
  return (
    <Col md={4}>
      <Carousel>
        {output}
      </Carousel>
      </Col>
  )

},

 renderData(item) {    

     return (
     <div>
      <Grid>
        <Row>
          {item.content.userData.firstName}
          {this.renderImages(item.content.medias)}
        </Row>
     </Grid>
     </div>
     )
},

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.discover.map(this.renderData)}
      </div>
    )
  }
})

var style = {};

style.carousel= {
    marginTop: '50',
    display: 'inline-block'
}

function mapStateToProps({ discover }) {
  return { discover }
}

    function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ fetchDiscovery },dispatch);
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ImageCarousel);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by moving the carousel to its own seperate component, and passed the data down as props, each carousel then rendered in a grid